# Automatic JSON deserialization with Jackson

Tags: json, jackson, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm kind new to Jackson and I have a web service that expects a JSON Object being passed via an HTTP POST request. The JSON Object is to be mapped to a Java class for further processing.

So I have this:

```
@Path("/")
public class RestService {
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public String postAction(MyClass json) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

MyClass looks something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    protected String var1;
    protected JSONArray var2;
}
```

Point is, that var2 is an array, holding JSONObjects (or being empty). These JSON Objects should be mapped to another class MySubClass, say

```
public class MySubClass {
    protected String subvar1;
}
```

So we'd have a matching String coming in via POST resembling a valid JSON object:

```
{"var1": "x", "var2": [{"subvar1": "1"},{"subvar1": "2"}]}
```

Problem is, that this crashes everytime with an error message like this:

> string(419) "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2015 15:53:26
>   GMT Content-Type: text/html Connection: close Server:
>   Jetty(9.2.2.v20140723) org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:
>   Can not deserialize instance of org.json.JSONArray out of START_ARRAY
>   token at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@2d6e16c7; line: 1, column: 1545]
>   (through reference chain: x.y.z.MyClass["var2"])"

Maybe I'm too tired by now to spot the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need a list of MySubClass or JsonArray.
Because in the string you have:

```
"var2": [{"subvar1": "1"},{"subvar1": "2"}]}
```

which is a collection. 
So in your MyClass you shoud have:

```
 public class MyClass {

    protected String var1;
    protected List<.....> var2;
 }
```

I hope this will help!!